# Do I have to include non-retina textures in SpriteKit app?

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

I could not find any answer for the following question:

Do I have to include non-retina textures in my SpriteKit app? Since SpriteKit supports iOS7+ only, and it won't run on non-retina iPhones, can I omit the non-retina images and use only @2x ? Should I expect any issues (assuming it runs only on iPhone)?

Currently my atlas files include only @2x.png files, and I use

```
_myNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"my_node_image@2x"];
```

If I omit the "@2x" it won't load the image correctly, but then again - can I use this and ignore non retina resolution?

Answer (score 3):

If your application is iPhone iOS7+ only. You can ignore non retina images.*

- Things might change if apple decides to release new non-retina iPhone, which seems highly unlikely. But you will probably have enough time to update your app with non-retina images in such case.

Comment: Are you sure about this? You sent for review an app iOS7 + excluding non-retina images?